# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I want to create a table using the following script:

```
mysql_query("create table `".$mysql_table_prefix."query_log` (
    query varchar(255),
    time timestamp(14),
    elapsed float(2),
    results int, 
    key query_key(query)
)");
```

It gives me this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql_query("create table `".$mysql_table_prefix."query_log` ( query varchar(25' at line 1
```

EDIT: I used sql tab in phpMyAdmin

What can I do?

Comment: How are you executing this script?

Comment: Your error looks like you're running your "query" inside a MySQL query. Can you post some the context that your above snippet is in?

Comment: What is the value of $mysql_table_prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using PHP in a place that expects plain SQL (note that the OP stated "I used sql tab in phpMyAdmin").  Cut it down to:

```
create table `query_log` (
    query varchar(255),
    time timestamp,
    elapsed float(2),
    results int, 
    key query_key(query)
)
```

And @Aurelio is right, there's no length parameter to timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

The first error I see is that `timestamp` does not have a lenght. So this line:

```
time timestamp(14),
```

should be like this:

```
time timestamp,
```

Comment: TIMESTAMP(n) was a valid method of using TIMESTAMP in MySQL, but was deprecated in 5.1, and completely removed in 5.5.  If you are running into this issue, please check your MySQL version via `mysql -v` and it will allow you to check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html for your respective version.

Answer (score 0):

Give your error message, you've screwed up the code somehow, such that the PHP mysql_query call is being treated as a string, then passed into mysql_query() directly. Possibly an unbalanced `'` on a previous line is causing this.

```
... syntax to use near 'mysql_query("create table ...
```

A properly constructed query string would never have a literal PHP function call in it.

If you are passing a PHP script to mysql directly at the command line, e.g.

```
$ mysql < somescript.php
```

this will also not work. MySQL will not execute that script. It will attempt to load the raw text of code the literally.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the whole text before passing it to the function:

```
    $params="create table `".$mysql_table_prefix."query_log` (
    query varchar(255),
    time timestamp(14),
    elapsed float(2),
    results int, 
    key query_key(query)
)"
```

Then just

```
mysql_query($params);
```